# MySQL Query : How to show all number and sum it

Tags: mysql

I have numeric data and I want to show all plus average value. How should I do to make it in MySQL?

Example : (2.5 is average value)

```
Data
------
1
2
3
4
2.5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it without union

```
SELECT
  AVG(value)
FROM a
GROUP BY id with rollup
```

Output

```
| VALUE |
|-------|
|     1 |
|     2 |
|     3 |
|     4 |
|   2.5 |
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/efa4c/2)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT Data FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT AVG(Data) AS Data FROM table
```

Comment: +1, Thanks. now both yours and @raheel shan 's query work well. My question is "which one is faster?", I wonder if OP test both queries and post test result...

Comment: @InoSHeo you have fiddle available you can use to see execution plan and execution time

Comment: @raheelshan Aha, Thank you very much. I'll try later. (it's time to go home. 7pm here.)